# Do objects pinned in Parse Local datastore get deleted as well when it's deleted on the backend?

Tags: parse-platform, local-datastore

Suppose that there are two iDevices:  `device1` and `device2`. Both devices have pinned some object `foobar` retrieved from the Parse backend.

`device1` performs a `-deleteEventually` on `foobar`. This causes the object to also be automatically unpinned. This deletion is propagated to the backend, and the backend now has removed foobar.

`device2` performs a query that would normally fetch `foobar`; except, it's missing.

What happens to `foobar` on `device2`'s local datastore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As local datastore is...local, then the object will be keeped in the second device until it receives an update about the objects, and pinned those again (after unpin obviously). No changes will be made in the second one if you are not requesting new objects from the Backend.

Comment: Yes so I think you're right about that — following my example, `foobar` is still pinned on `device2`, and so performing a query will not change the local datastore: `foobar` will still be available.

If you want the deletion to occur locally as well, you must manually specify that you want `foobar` unpinned for the deletion to occur.

This is documented under 'caching queries' section of the Parse LDS guide.
https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#localdatastore-caching/iOS

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for this type of issue that I'm using in my app:

1. using PFQuery fetch objects from parse
2. make query local and fetch objects from local storage
3. unpin objects if they was found in local storage
4. pin objects that came from network

And code sample:

```
- (BFTask *)find:(PFQuery *)query {
    return [[query findObjectsInBackground] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
        BFTask *(^pin)(void) = ^ {
            return [[PFObject pinAllInBackground:task.result] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                                  withSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
                                                                      return task.result;
                                                                  }];
        };

        [query fromLocalDatastore];
        return [[query findObjectsInBackground] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
            if (!task.error && [task.result count]) {
                return [[PFObject unpinAllInBackground:task.result] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
                    return pin();
                }];
            } else {
                return pin();
            }
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Hi Nastya
Nice solution, but you are grabbing all the PFobject everytimes.

Any solution to get only the new datas? (Including the deleted from dashboard)

(see my post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323192/parse-keep-localdatastore-data-sync)