# Parse sync of deleted objects

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I want to use Parse in my project for the first time, for sync data between devices and store them in cloud. One thing that I can't understand properly - is how to sync deleted objects.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323192/parse-keep-localdatastore-data-sync%20*here*) @Javier de la Cueva gave good answer (*not use a physical delete but a logical. Add a new Boolean columns called "deleted", and "sync", and  background job will delete objects with sync = YES.*). This approach will work perfectly if user has only 2 ways (devices, web, ...) to work with app. But what if he has 3 or more ways (devices)?

For example, he has 3 devices, all of them synced. Then he doing next: On device A he created something, on device B he deleted it, then run app on device A he sync - saw that object has flag "deleted" - and deleted it locally, sent flag "sync" to Parse. Then, after some time background job deleted this object.

**Here is the problem:**  Then user run the app from device C, he try to sync, but don't see any changes, and really deleted object still exist, he can update it, and send to Parse. And after - devices A and B downloaded it again!

I can see only 2 **solutions** here:

***First***: config this background job to begin every `N` days, and when syncing, if we see that we get objects with `updatedAt` date more than `N` days than our local last `updatedAt` date - we assume that data *irrevocable obsoleted* and we have to remove all local data, and download all again from Parse (we can just update and add data on this stage, but what if some of our local objects must be deleted and we don't know about it? Or it's possible to set `fetchRequest` get all data except bunch of `objectIDs` (it can be hundreds)?)

**Second solution** that I see is to have `DeletedObjectsIDs` table and check it for needed to delete objects.
   I would like to know - are my suggestions right? What solution is better or more smarter ways to sync deletion exist?

Comment: How does C not see changes? The object has been updated and is marked as deleted. You don't actually need to delete the objects, just mark them as deleted.

Comment: @Wain because Background job deleted this object (this object had "deleted" and "sync" flags to YES) Why I don't need to delete them? After some time can be thousands of deleted objects, deleted more than a year, why I should store them? After all Parse database not unlimited